# How to install deepin system monitor in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.10, system-monitor, deepin-desktop-environment

How do I install deepin system monitor in Ubuntu 20.10

[image: deepin system monitor]

Answer (score 4):

It is available in [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages) PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install deepin-system-monitor
```

The PPA is provided by the devs of Ubuntu DDE Remix, so I would trust them. If you don't want to add the PPA you can simply grab the [.deb files](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/deepin-system-monitor_5.6.24-3_amd64.deb) from the above link.